# Blocking Queue Take() does not retrieve the item

Tags: java, multithreading, blockingqueue

I have the code below:

```
@Override
public boolean start() {
    boolean b = false;
    if (status != RUNNING) {
        LOGGER.info("Starting Auto Rescheduler Process...");
        try {
            b = super.start();
            final ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("Rescheduler-Pool-%d").build();
            ExecutorService exServ = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(threadFactory);

            service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(exServ);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error starting Auto Rescheduler Process! {}", e.getMessage());
            LOGGER.debug("{}", e);
            b = false;
        }
    } else {
        LOGGER.info("Asked to start Auto Rescheduler Process but it had already started. Ignoring...");
    }
    return b;
}
```

The `AutoRescheduler` is the runnable below:

```
private class AutoScheduler implements Runnable {

    private static final String DEFAULT_CONFIGURABLE_MINUTES_VALUE = "other";
    private static final long DEFAULT_DELAY_MINUTES = 60L;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                //BLOCKS HERE UNTIL A FINISHED EVENT IS PUT IN QUEUE
                final FinishedEvent fEvent = finishedEventsQueue.take();
                LOGGER.info("Received a finished Event for {} and I am going to reschedule it", fEvent);
                final MyTask task = fEvent.getSource();
                final LocalDateTime nextRunTime = caclulcateNextRightTime(task);
                boolean b = scheduleEventService.scheduleEventANew(task, nextRunTime);
                if (b) {
                    cronController.loadSchedule();
                    LOGGER.info("Rescheduled event {} for {}", task, nextRunTime);
                }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Interrupted while waiting for a new finishedEventQueue");
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
```

I see events being caught and put in the queue. Normally I then see them being rescheduled by the `AutoReschduler`

However from time to time I stop seeing them being rescheduled which leads me to believe that the `reschedulingThread` dies silently. After this happens no more events are taken from the queue until I restart the process (I have a GUI that allows me to call the `stop()` and `start()` methods of the public class). After I restart it though, the blocked events are rescheduled normally which means that they are in the queue indeed.

Does anyone have an idea?

***EDIT***

I have reproduced the error in Eclipse. The thread does not die (I have tested with the `ExecutorService` as well. However `take()` still does not take the item from the queue although it is placed there.

Comment: When you suspect that the reschedulingThread has died, have you taken a thread dump to confirm?

Comment: No I have not. I am not sure how to do this. My app is running in tomcat 7.

Comment: `kill -7 <pid>` or use `jvisualvm`

Comment: Since this is an application running on the server and I cannot just kill the process (maybe I could do a jvisualvm). Also this issue is very erratic. I have seen in very few times and I cannot reproduce it. That is why I put the code up. If someone sees something obviously wrong with what I am doing it would be great.

Comment: `kill -7` should not kill a jvm process. It will pause it and print its stack trace to stdout and then resume it.

Comment: ok. Thanks I will try it out.